# Comparar 2 bancos

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Bom dia, tenho dois bancos Access, um é cópia do outro, mas um deles tem um registro que foi adicionado, não sei em qual tabela ou campo, gostaria de compara-los e achar qual tabela, campo foi alterado.

Comment: Pode usar o [Free Database Compare 2.0](https://icoder.azurewebsites.net/sqlcompare02.htm)

Comment: soh fazer o download ddesse arquivo http://dbweigher.com/download.php